# C++17 Copy elision object lifetime

Tags: c++, move-semantics, copy-elision, return-value-optimization, c++-faq

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> URVO is mandatory and no longer considered a form of copy elision.

> When copy elision occurs, the implementation treats the source and
> target of the omitted copy/move(since C++11) operation as simply two
> different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
> that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
> would have been destroyed without the optimization (except that, if
> the parameter of the selected constructor is an rvalue reference to
> object type, the destruction occurs when the target would have been
> destroyed)(since C++11).

Could anyone provide an example of copy elision where the selected constructor is not the move constructor (i.e. not the exception case mentioned in parenthesis) and the target gets destroyed earlier than the source? Why should the lifetime be different (warranting an exception) when the selected constructor is the move constructor - i.e. any problem with the lifetime being the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _where the selected constructor is not the move constructor_?  Because the whole point of this is that the source and target objects _are the same thing_, so nothing ever needs to be moved (or copied).  The temporary constructed in the return statement it just magically teleported to the call site.  By magic.

Comment: @PaulSanders When I say _where the selected constructor is not the move constructor_ I mean not the exception case mentioned at the end: _(except that, if the parameter of the selected constructor is an rvalue reference to object type...)_

Comment: *"is not the move constructor"*. It might be the copy constructor...

Comment: *"target gets destroyed earlier than the source"* I don't see how it is possible.

Comment: @Jarod42 Then why the wording _the later of the times when the two objects would have been destroyed without the optimization_?

Comment: When you pass a temporary by value to a function, the target (which is the parameter) gets destroyed earlier than the source (which is the argument).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The scenario you mentioned is [prvalue semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and no longer considered a form of copy elision.

Comment: So it is a case which requires that wording (which is not wrong in C++17, but might possibly be simplified (but would complexify wording handling all versions)).

Comment: The bracketed part seems to be a garbled rewording of [CWG1967](https://wg21.link/CWG1967) (but "an rvalue reference to object type" should be "an rvalue reference to the object's type"). I'm also not entirely sure if it is necessary wording (it requires a case where the target would be destroyed before the source of the copy elision)

Comment: @Jarod42 If it's UVRO, it won't be any constructor, will it?  Or have I got this all wrong.

Comment: @PaulSanders: post C++17, no constructors indeed (both(copy and move) might even be deleted). pre C++17, constructor should be available, even if elided.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes (see question title :)